# What does ["string"].pack('H*') mean?

Tags: ruby, hex, digest

I need to translate some Ruby code to JavaScript and came across the following function:

```
def sha1_hex(h)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([h].pack('H*'))
end
```

What exactly does `[h].pack('H*')` mean in this context? How would it translate to JavaScript?

Comment: .pack('H') will pack the contents of an array into Hex string.

Comment: I've looked at the doc, but "hex string (high nibble first)" didn't mean much to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It interprets the string as hex numbers, two characters per byte, and converts it to a string with the characters with the corresponding ASCII code:

```
["464F4F"].pack('H*')  # =>  "FOO", 0x46 is the code for 'F', 0x4F the code for 'O'
```

For the opposite conversion, use `unpack`:

```
'FOO'.unpack('H*')     # => ["464f4f"]
```

It is a little bit more difficult for non-ASCII-8BIT encodings:

```
"á".encoding                                # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
"á".unpack('H*')                            # => ["c3a1"]
['c3a1'].pack('H*')                         # => "\xC3\xA1"
['c3a1'].pack('H*').encoding                # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
['c3a1'].pack('H*').force_encoding('UTF-8') # => "á"
```