# How to convert a hexadecimal string back to it's 'SecureRandom.random_bytes' binary?

Tags: ruby, encryption, binary, hex

In Ruby, I can create a 16 byte binary and convert it to a hexadecimal string:

```ruby
key     = SecureRandom.random_bytes(16)                    # => "hN\xDB\xAD\xAF\xB3R\xC0`\xB19\x1D\x19.\xD3I"
hex_key = key.each_byte.map { |byte| '%02x' % byte }.join  # => "684edbadafb352c060b1391d192ed349"
```

In PHP and Javascript I can convert the the hexadecimal string back to it's 16 byte binary.

PHP:

```php
<?php
hex2bin("684edbadafb352c060b1391d192ed349");
?>
```

Javascript [via CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/wikis/QuickStartGuide_v3beta.wiki):

```js
CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("684edbadafb352c060b1391d192ed349");
```

But how do I convert the hexadecimal string back to it's 16 byte binary, using Ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \["string"\].pack('H\*') mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623668/what-does-string-packh-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
[str].pack('H*').bytes.to_a
```

or just

```
[str].pack('H*')
```

Comment: I think it's just `[str].pack('H*')`