# To convert ruby unpack equivalent in java

Tags: java, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unpack

I'm trying to understand this line of ruby code:

```
token.unpack('m0').first.unpack('H*').first
```

which is converting

```
R1YKdH//cZKubZlA09ZIVZQ5/cxInvmokIACnl3MKJ0=
```

to

```
47560a747fff7192ae6d9940d3d648559439fdcc489ef9a89080029e5dcc289d
```

As far as I understand this, it is base64 to hex conversion, but when I try to do the same thing, its not matching with converted one.

I need to implement the same functionality in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to break this down. The first step is `token.unpack('m0')`. According to [Idiosyncratic Ruby](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/4-what-the-pack.html#m0--base64-encoding-rfc-4648) `unpack('m0')` will decode base64, similarly to the built-in `Base64` libararies `Base64.decode64(string)` function. But unpack returns an arry here, with only 1 element, the converted base64. So we use `token.unpack('m0').first` to get the first (and in this case the only) element of the array returned by `token.unpack('m0')`. If this was all, then you'd be correct to say that it's just base64. But, the unpacked base64 is unpacked again, this time with [`'H*'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623668/what-does-string-packh-mean/17624804#17624804), which will convert the characters to hex. And finally, because that will return an array, you use first again to make it only a string.

So in summary, what is happening is that first your string is being decoded from base64 to a string, then it's being converted to hex.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for asking a clear, well structured question which makes it easier to write an answer!

Comment: @KamleshArya can you share your equivalent java code here?