# Decrypting keys from aws-kms in Ruby

Tags: node.js, ruby, serverless-framework, amazon-kms

I’m using [serverless-kms-secrets](https://github.com/nordcloud/serverless-kms-secrets) on serverless frameword to set some ENV variables I want to consume using Ruby.

I can confirm that the plugin works perfectly, it generated the file with the encrypted variable and I can see the encrypted variable in my environment on AWS lambda.
The problem is that I can’t decrypt it in Ruby. The code that decrypts it (correctly) in the plugin is [here](https://github.com/nordcloud/serverless-kms-secrets/blob/master/index.js#L81-L94), I understand it gets the string saved in the file and encodes it using Base64, so no big deal.
In Ruby:

```
token = "blablabla"
client = Aws::KMS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
blob = Base64.encode64(token)
client.decrypt({ciphertext_blob: blob})
....
Aws::KMS::Errors::InvalidCiphertextException ()
```

The client should get my credentials automatically, but I’m not sure I understand how the keyArn is used, doesn’t look relevant though.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of encoding the string I had to decode it.

```
token = "blablabla"
client = Aws::KMS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
blob = Base64.decode64(token)
client.decrypt({ciphertext_blob: blob})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `ciphertext_blob` argument in `Aws::KMS::Client#decrypt` [expects a binary string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/KMS/Client.html#decrypt-instance_method) that includes [the encrypted Ciphertext that you want to decrypt](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/KMS/Types/DecryptRequest.html#ciphertext_blob-instance_method).

In your example, you are passing in an *unencrypted Base64 encoded string* into `decrypt`. Instead, you need to to pass in an *encrypted binary string*.

To get an encrypted string we can call `Aws::KMS::Client#encrypt` with your keyId (also know as your ARN) and the string you want to encrypt in plaintext.

In the response from that call we get back a `ciphertext_blob` which is the encrypted binary string that we need to use in order to decode.

Sometimes you might see that binary data "unpacked", which you can demonstrate doing `ciphertext_blob.unpack('H*')`. If you have unpacked data and want to decrypt it, you will need to pack it: `encrypted_upacked_blob.pack('H*')`.

Here's a full example of a round trip encoding and decoding of a plaintext string:

```
require 'aws-sdk-kms'

client = Aws::KMS::Client.new

key_id = 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab'

plaintext_to_encrypt = 'blablabla'

encrypt_response = client.encrypt({
  key_id: key_id,
  plaintext: plaintext_to_encrypt,
})

encrypt_response.ciphertext_blob
# => "\x01\x02\x02\x00xt/Jyu\x85B\xCA\x16v\xDAa3DM1$\e8Y\xF9\x812\x1E\xA9\xD3\xE3R\x1E/}\xCA\x...

encrypted_upacked_blob = encrypt_response.ciphertext_blob.unpack('H*')
# => ["0102020078742f4a79758542ca1676da6133444d31241b3859f981321ea9d3e3521e2f7dca01a7f89f2ee03...

encrypted_packed_blob = encrypted_upacked_blob.pack('H*')
# => "\x01\x02\x02\x00xt/Jyu\x85B\xCA\x16v\xDAa3DM1$\e8Y\xF9\x812\x1E\xA9\xD3\xE3R\x1E/}\xCA\x...

decrypt_response = client.decrypt({
  ciphertext_blob: encrypted_packed_blob
})

decrypted_plaintext = decrypt_response.plaintext
# => "blablabla"
```

This example combines two examples provided by AWS: [Encrypting Data in AWS KMS using Ruby SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/kms-example-encrypt-data.html) and [Decrypting a Data Blob in AWS KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/kms-example-decrypt-blob.html).

For a better understand of what `[blob].pack("H*")` is doing, check out [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623668/what-does-string-packh-mean) and Ruby's [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-pack) documentation.

Comment: Nothing changes, still `Aws::KMS::Errors::InvalidCiphertextException ()`

Comment: @ngw it looks like you were using an unencrypted string when it needs to be encrypted. I updated my answer to take that into account and provided a full example that I just tested.

Comment: Nope, it’s encrypted by the node.js library

Comment: @ngw okay, how are you getting it from the node.js library to Ruby?

Comment: I just followed the instructions on https://github.com/nordcloud/serverless-kms-secrets. I have both a yaml file with the encrypted value in and the same thing in my ENV. I'm sure it's encrypted correctly because I can decrypt it using js.